# How do I pass inputs into SCSS for an Angular component?

Tags: angular

I am trying to write an Angular component, I want it styled using SCSS.  That part I got already done, but I can't figure out how to make part of the SCSS dynamically set with an input variable.

```
@Component({
  selector: "dh-artifact",
  templateUrl: "dh-artifact.html",
  inputs: ["size"],
})
export class DhArtifactComponent implements OnInit {
...
```

Say I want to set the image border with the `size` parameter

```
dh-artifact {
  img {
    border: ${size}px solid black;
  }
}
```

And the template is

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set in CSS

```
 img {
   border: solid black;
}
```

and in your HTML

```
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" [ngStyle]="{'border-width': size + 'px'}"/>
```

Comment: The thing is you're bypassing the SCSS, which is what I wanted to avoid.